# IdHttp: redirect to error page when trying to download a file, __viewstate changes each time

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, indy, indy10, idhttp

i have already successfully logged in and posted data and downloaded data from 2 sites using idHttp.post(), but i am having trouble with the third one
in this new site, the login does work, but when i try to download a file (which uses __doPostBack for the download link) i get redirected to an error page
i have double and triple checked all post datas and they are exactly like what http analyzer showed me **the only difference i noticed is that in my other attempts and sites that i accessed successfully,__viewstate is the same each time, and it never changes but in this third site it changes with each login** (i mean when i go to the site manually and i check http analyzer results i can see that __viewstate parameter value differs each time)
**what should i do ? is the problem with that changing __viewstate paramter ? if so how can i fix it ?**
the code i use for posting :

```
try
 Response := TMemoryStream.Create;
try
  Request := TStringList.Create;
  try
    Request.Assign(TATDFileUtility.convertPairValueToRequestList(TATDFileUtility.extractPairValue('the site login parameters.txt', 3)));
    IdHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create;
    try
      IdHTTP.AllowCookies := True;
      IdHTTP.HandleRedirects := True;
      IdHTTP.Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';

      IdHTTP.Post('thesite, the address for the login and main page and download page is the same', Request, Response);
      Response.SaveToFile('responseCode0.txt');

      Request.Clear;
      Response.Clear;
      Request.Assign(TATDFileUtility.convertPairValueToRequestList(TATDFileUtility.extractPairValue('httpDownloadParamters.txt', 3)));
      IdHTTP.Post('thesite, the address for the login and main page and download page is the same', Request, Response);
      Response.SaveToFile('responseCode1.txt');
```

as you can see after checking repsonsecode0, i can see that i am logged in, but the second response code shows me an error and tracking it shows that i am getting redirected to an error page.

Comment: What do you expect? We don't know which site, we don't see any code, we can just guess. You lie that you send exactly the same - you don't. You have to access login site first to obtain correct __viewstate value. Then login with this value and then check again if the value was changed and use the new one. It is easy to fix it - just send correct value.

Comment: @smooty86, for privacy reasons, i can not share the site address but the code is as you see above.

Comment: @smooty86, if i need to dynamically get __viewstate, how can i do that ?, how can i get the current __viewstate value so that i can give it to my program ?, thx

Comment: Save Response into TStringList, not stream (or move it from stream to any string). It is just a text. Then you parse it (you can use just Pos and Copy to get the value). Do not set `IdHTTP.Request.ContentType` (it is automatic).

Comment: thx for the tips, right now the problem is that response code is an error page, and it should be a file, a zip file(i should get redirect to a download page which as i save the response code, im saving that downloaded file)

Comment: You probably do not send valid authorization or any header. It can depend on any variable you send so you have to make sure you send it correctly. We can't find out from nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ViewState is dynamic.  You need to first `GET` the HTML page that defines the `<form>` element that normally submits the PostBack in a browser.  This allows the webserver to generate the current ViewState.  Then parse the HTML to extract the names and values of the `<input>` elements within the `<form>`, including the ViewState, and then you can `POST` those values to the URL specified in the `<form>`'s `action` attribute.  This is what a web browser normally does, and what you need to simulate with `TIdHTTP`.

Comment: thank you !, indeed the viewstate and other parameters are there after i use GET, ill try to use the dynamic viewstate and ill share the result, for now one question, does the order of parameters inside request list matter ?, i mean for example is it ok for viewstate to be the last parameter ?

Comment: Order may or may not matter, depending on the server implementation. The HTML spec states that `<input>` values should be submitted in the order they are declared in the HTML.

Comment: after logging, i used GET, and parsed it using TRegEx, and added __ViewState and __eventValidation, and there was no more error page!! and it fixed it ! BUT, even though i was not redirected to error page the response code return by the last POST, does not contain the file ! and its an html code very much like the previous steps, i should note that my login page, main page and download page are the same address

Comment: @AliAhmadi did you read the HTML to see what it says? It could still be an error page. Not all errors are reported at the HTTP layer, sometimes a webserver sends an HTTP success response containing an error message in HTML

Comment: yes i open it with internet explorer as an html and there was no error but there was one big difference from the html before it, and it was that after login , the page contains all kind of link but after the post the links are gone.

Comment: Problem Solved!!! you are the best !, the reason it didnt work was because after log in i would call GET and then use that response code __viewstate, but i should have used the log in post response code as used that __viewstate for the second post, anyway i did it and it worked, Thank you!

Comment: Thankyou *very* much for your comment on this - it gave me the missing piece in my current project. Fortunately for me, my target site doesn't change the __VIEWSTATE so that made my task a bit easier - but the flipside was some insane html layout.